# How to exactly specify (iterate over) the children of newData?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am new to Firebase Realtime Database. I would like people to be able to write new messages, but the data written can only contain information on the sender, and the text of the message. How can I make sure the objects sent only contain sender and content and nothing else?

```
"messages":{
  "$message":{
    ...,
    ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.hasChildren(['sender', 'content'])"
   }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to ensure only certain child nodes are present is to reject all other nodes with a wildcard rule. In your code that'd look something like:

```js
"messages":{
  "$message":{
    "sender": { ".validate": true },
    "content": { ".validate": true },
    "$other": { ".validate": false }
  }
}
```

The rules engine will first match `sender` and `content` to the named rules and allow them, and then match all other nodes to the wildcard and reject them.